# org.hibernate.MappingException: <mapping> element in configuration specifies no known attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, mapping

When i run the code it gives me an exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException:  element in configuration specifies no known attributes

I am not sure where error occurs, can anyone help me to solve this..

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
     <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
     <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">"url"</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">"username"</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">"password"</property>
<mapping resource="student.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping/>
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

private String name;
 private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}

Regular.java

 public class Regular extends Student {

String coursefees;

public String getCoursefees() {
    return coursefees;
}

public void setCoursefees(String coursefees) {
    this.coursefees = coursefees;
}

}
```

**Distant.java**

```
 public class Distant extends Student {

String distantfees;

public String getDistantfees() {
    return distantfees;
}

public void setDistantfees(String distantfees) {
    this.distantfees = distantfees;
}

}
```

**student.hbm.xml**

```
       <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

       <hibernate-mapping>


       <class name="pojos.Student" table="student" discriminator-       value="student">  
       <id name="id" type="int">  
       <column name="id"/>
       <generator class="increment"></generator>  
       </id>  

       <discriminator column="type" type="string"></discriminator>  
       <property name="name" type="string">
       <column name="sname"/>
        </property>

     <subclass name="pojos.Regular" discriminator-value="regstud">  
     <property name="coursefees" type="string">
     <column name="coursefees"/>
     </property>  
    </subclass>   

   <subclass name="pojos.Distant" discriminator-value="distant">  
   <property name="distantfees" type="string">
  <column name="distfees"/>
  </property>  
  </subclass>

 </class>

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException:  element in configuration specifies no known attributes
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2286)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove that empty `<mapping/>` at the end of your hibernate.cfg.xml file